# Max number of records allowed in a recordset?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, vb6, recordset

I have a recordset, where i am adding a new row to it. I was using

```
rs.Update
rs.Requery
rs.MoveLast
```

to get the row i just added. It was working perfectly fine however when the recordset went up to about 50k+ it would not go beyond a certain point. Is there a max amount of records in recordset? I have no rs.maxrecords defined and according to that property leaving it as 0 makes it unlimited. Also beyond is there an easier way to get the row i just added. Besides doing a max(ID) requery?

Comment: Just saying "it would not go beyond a certain point" doesn't help. What actually happens? Is there an error? What line is the error on?

Comment: is this recordset filtered?

Comment: Do you really need to be requerying 50k records every time you add a new one?  Why not start again with an empty recordset ?

Answer (score 0):

I would instead doing this like so when the IDENTITY-Column is called id:
    INSERT INTO YourSchema.YourTable (column1,column2)
    OUTPUT inserted.id
    VALUES ('X', 'Y');
This will not only insert the roecord but also giving a Recordset back with the id from the inserted record.